# CSS: Extending input box in a form generated with Rails' `form_for`?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, devise

So I'm pretty new to frontend, so I have a simple CSS question:

I have a form generated with Devise with the `form_for` method as follows:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => "form-signin"} ) do |f| %>

  <div class="account-wall">    
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Email' %><br />

      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Password' %>

      <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
        <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
      <% end %>

      <%= f.submit "Sign in" %>

  </div>

<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

My stylesheets:

```
.form-signin
{
    max-width: 330px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.account-wall
{
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 40px 0px 20px 0px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.form-signin .form-control
{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 6px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This is what the code above produces:

[image]

What is the easiest way to center the input boxes/remember me/button within the `account-wall` and make them a bit wider?

Generated HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
      <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/guest/actives/sign_in" class="form-signin" id="new_active" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="kCoKZR1wtX5dTGuvw8p+P0ZsTi3vBEv08IQXh+IOWhM=" /></div>

  <div class="account-wall">    
      <img class="profile-img" src="../../assets/akpsi_bw_200.png" alt="akpsi_color_200">
      <input autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control" id="active_email" name="active[email]" placeholder="Email" type="email" value="" /><br />

      <input autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control" id="active_password" name="active[password]" placeholder="Password" type="password" />

        <div><input name="active[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="active_remember_me" name="active[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1" /> <label for="active_remember_me">Remember me</label></div>

      <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign in" />

  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Can you post your currently generated html as well?

Comment: I think setting `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` would work when applied to the elements within the account-wall, but you'd need to manually set a width for the elements. But then, since you wanted to make them wider, that shouldn't be a problem, just set a `width` value for them in the CSS.

Comment: you just need to add  text-align:center; to your .form-signin class and elements will be centered. .account-wall input[type=email], .account-wall input[type=password]{margin:5px 5px;width:280px;}
.account-wall div{display:inline-block;} these will help you to enlarge the input and make the checkbox and button within one line. see my demo below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/LPWwP/)

```
.form-signin
{
    max-width: 330px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align:center; /*add this;*/
}

.account-wall
{
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 40px 0px 20px 0px;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
/*add below*/
.account-wall input[type=email], .account-wall input[type=password]{margin:5px 5px;width:280px;}
.account-wall div{display:inline-block;}
.account-wall button{display:inline-block;}
```

[Updated demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/LPWwP/1/)

```
/*add below*/
.account-wall input[type=email], .account-wall input[type=password]{margin:5px 5px;width:280px;}
.account-wall div{display:inline-block; width:165px;}
.account-wall input[type=submit]{width:110px;}
```

Comment: Thanks. One more thing -- now, everything is centered, including both input fields, the checkbox, the text "Remember Me", and the button. How do I align _just_ the checkbox and "Remember Me" to the left edge of the input field boxes?

Comment: Thanks, accepted the answer! One last thing, if I may: say there's an attribute of my User model that is a short paragraph "biography," and my code to generate such a field is like so:

`<%= f.text_area :biography, class: 'form-control bio-field', autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Biography'  %>`.

My styling looks like:

`.bio-field {
    width: 80%;
    height: 50%;
}`

Why is it that the width of the input box stretches appropriately after I apply this styling, but the height never expands beyond about 2.5~ rows?

Comment: 2 suggestions:1. use rows="10" cols="10" in textarea in case the height is not supported in some browsers, in this case you can use height:auto in your css; 2. your % value for height diesn't work because you don't have a parent value to inherit from, if you give it a fixed value say 80px it will work perfectly, otherwise you'll have to define a height of your parent wrapper which is not the best solution